# How obtain a (accurate) function from this graph with these points?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, interpolation, approximation-theory

I need obtain the function from 0 to 20 from this graph:

[image]

I have the even numbers in the {x, f(x)} format:
{0, 0}, {2, 1.8}, {4, 2}, {6, 4}, {8,4}, {10,6}, {12,4}, {14,3.6},{16,3.4}, {18,2.8}, {20,0}

I tried using interpolation from Wolfram Alpha but It got the Runge's phenomenon as you can see in this link [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+{0%2C+0}%2C+{2%2C+1.8}%2C+{4%2C+2}%2C+{6%2C+4}%2C+{8%2C4}%2C+{10%2C6}%2C+{12%2C4}%2C+{14%2C3.6}%2C{16%2C3.4}%2C+{18%2C2.8}%2C+{20%2C0}](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating%20polynomial%20%7B0%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B2%2C%201.8%7D%2C%20%7B4%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7B6%2C%204%7D%2C%20%7B8%2C4%7D%2C%20%7B10%2C6%7D%2C%20%7B12%2C4%7D%2C%20%7B14%2C3.6%7D%2C%7B16%2C3.4%7D%2C%20%7B18%2C2.8%7D%2C%20%7B20%2C0%7D)

So, if anyone could give me a relatively accurate approximation I would be very grateful.

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: Can you give more information? What is this supposed to model? There must be additional requirements if you are sure the exact polynomial fit is no good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [cubic spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) does the job:

[image: spline]

There are infinitely many programs for spline interpolation. I rolled my own, however (in [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)). It computes cubic spline by considering it as a "correction" to piecewise linear interpolation.

```
a = 0
b = 20
y = [0 1.8 2 4 4 6 4 3.6 3.4 2.8 0]
n = length(y)-1
h = (b-a)/n
jumps = diff(y,2)/h
A = (h/6)*(diag(4*ones(1,n-1))+diag(ones(1,n-2),1)+diag(ones(1,n-2),-1))
z = [0,-jumps/A,0] 
allx = []
spl = []
for i=1:n  
   xL = a+h*(i-1)
   xR = a+h*i
   x = linspace(xL,xR,100)
   linear = y(i)*(xR-x)/h + y(i+1)*(x-xL)/h
   correction = ((z(i+1)+2*z(i))*(xR-x)+(2*z(i+1)+z(i))*(x-xL)).*(xR-x).*(x-xL)/(6*h)
   allx = [allx, x]   
   spl = [spl, linear+correction] 
end
plot(allx, spl) 
plot(a:h:b, y, 'r*')
```

A spline is a *piecewise* defined function; instead of a single complicated formula you have a bunch of simple formulas. Let $(x_1,y_1),\dots, (x_{11},y_{11})$ be the  points in your post. The code calculates numbers $z_1,\dots,z_{11}$ which you can get by simply typing `z` after running the program. The formula for the spline is as follows: 
when $x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}$, $$\begin{split}
y &= y_i\frac{x_{i+1} -x}{h}  + y_{i+1}\frac{x-x_i}{h} \\
&+ \frac{(x-x_i)(x_{i+1}-x)}{6h}((z_{i+1}+2 z_i) (x_{i+1} -x)+ (2 z_{i+1}+z_i) (x-x_i)) 
\end{split}$$
where $h=2$ (space between $x$-coordinates of the points). The first line is   the [piecewise linear interpolant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Interpolation_of_a_data_set). The second line is the cubic correction term. It must vanish  at the nodes of interpolation, hence the factor $(x-x_i)(x_{i+1}-x)$. This leaves only a linear factor of correction term to figure out,  which is done by using the condition that the first derivative of the correction term must jump at the interpolation node to negate the jump of the slope of the piecewise linear interpolant.

The numbers $z_i$ are actually $y''(x_i)$, as you can check by taking the derivative of $y$ above. This is a *natural cubic spline*, for which $y''$ vanishes at the endpoints.

Comment: Thank you, it is very accurate! But, how can I make Scilab give me the resulted function? I understand your code uses vectors and variables to make the curves and the "spl" from the line "plot(allx, spl) " should be the function in form of various points (or at least was what I think). So, how can I see the points in the form of a function? Ex: 23x²-3x-43.453; cos²x+23x; Sorry if it is a stupid question, I never used an math software before.

Comment: @user3676848 This is the sort of task that calls for math software. Scilab is a free download. See the explanation I added to   the answer.

Comment: @user3676848 A more detailed explanation of the above code [is here](http://calculus7.org/2014/02/14/connecting-dots-naturally/).